# change content disposition of a list in R

Tags: r

I've got a list with more than 5000 elements and I want to save them in a .csv data frame with specific disposition.

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.omie.es/aplicaciones/datosftp/datosftp.jsp?path=/marginalpdbc/"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
free(doc)
head(links)

wanted <- links[grepl("http*", links)]
head(wanted)
GetMe <- paste("", wanted, sep = "")

datos<-lapply(seq_along(GetMe),
              function(x) read.csv(GetMe[x], header = F, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE,skip=1))
```

Like this I've got 7 variables with 25 instances in each list element.

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4    V5         V6 V7
1  1999  1  1  1 3.350 0.02030303 NA
2  1999  1  1  2 3.595 0.02178788 NA
3  1999  1  1  3 3.293 0.01995758 NA
4  1999  1  1  4 2.800 0.01696970 NA
5  1999  1  1  5 2.516 0.01524848 NA
6  1999  1  1  6 2.516 0.01524848 NA
7  1999  1  1  7 2.516 0.01524848 NA
8  1999  1  1  8 2.516 0.01524848 NA
9  1999  1  1  9 2.516 0.01524848 NA
10 1999  1  1 10 2.516 0.01524848 NA
11 1999  1  1 11 2.516 0.01524848 NA
12 1999  1  1 12 2.840 0.01721212 NA
13 1999  1  1 13 2.840 0.01721212 NA
14 1999  1  1 14 3.595 0.02178788 NA
15 1999  1  1 15 3.586 0.02173333 NA
16 1999  1  1 16 2.840 0.01721212 NA
17 1999  1  1 17 2.840 0.01721212 NA
18 1999  1  1 18 2.840 0.01721212 NA
19 1999  1  1 19 4.172 0.02528485 NA
20 1999  1  1 20 3.639 0.02205455 NA
21 1999  1  1 21 3.661 0.02218788 NA
22 1999  1  1 22 3.661 0.02218788 NA
23 1999  1  1 23 3.661 0.02218788 NA
24 1999  1  1 24 3.638 0.02204848 NA
25    * NA NA NA    NA         NA NA
```

I want to have them all in the same dataframe with the following disposition:

```
FECHA   A„O MES DIASEM  DIA H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15
01/01/2003  2003    1   M   1   15  10.97   8.22    5.24    2.65    2.13    2.06    0.02    0   0   0.77    2.1 3.5 5.33    6.33
02/01/2003  2003    1   J   2   8.33    4.2 2.87    2.63    2.56    2.56    3.51    5.15    10  17.17   20  21.02   21.02   20  17.62
03/01/2003  2003    1   V   3   14.27   9.47    5.08    3.57    3.01    3.01    4.61    9.41    12.83   16.27   17.62   19.66   19.6    17.62   16.2
```

Where V1 is the year, V2 is the month, V3 is the day, V4 is de hour and V6 of the list corresponds to the values of each row.

In the final data frame each hour has to be one column.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `do.call("rbind.data.frame", x)` will take a list and turn it into a data.frame. You could then use `cast` from the `reshape2` package to turn it into wide format. Or maybe I've totally misinterpreted what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I also tried to do this:`for(i in 1:length(datos)){
   #assign(paste0("df", i),na.omit(assign(paste0("df", i),datos[[i]][1:6])))
  assign(paste0("df", i),as.data.frame(t(na.omit(assign(paste0("df", i),datos[[i]][5:6])))))
}`. And I obtained multiple data frames with a format like the one I want, but I couldn't achive to insert columns with the date.